# Compose - every column to take max height in a row based on text height

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have a row which is divided in to three columns and each column has a text in it.

Text is different in each column, I want all column height to be same based on the longest text, for example here I want all the height of all columns to be same as `Testt + Test`

I tried using `.height(intrinsicSize = IntrinsicSize.Max)` for the column but that did not work,

please suggest

this is the code I have tried

```
    @Composable
   fun SolarToggles(
        modifier: Modifier = Modifier
   ) {
    val options = listOf(
            "Testt off",
            "Testt + Test",
            "Off"
    )
    var selectedOption by remember {
        mutableStateOf("Solar off")
    }
    val onSelectionChange = { text: String ->
        selectedOption = text
    }

    Row(
            modifier = modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .padding(horizontal = 18.dp)
                    .clip(shape = RoundedCornerShape(
                            size = 3.dp,
                    ))
                    .background(md_theme_accessible_blue)
    ) {
        options.forEach { text ->
            Column(
                    modifier = Modifier
                            .height(intrinsicSize = IntrinsicSize.Max)
                            .padding(
                                    all = 3.dp,
                            )
                            .background(Color.Red)
                            .weight(1f)
                            .align(Alignment.CenterVertically)
            ) {
                Text(
                        text = text,
                        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                        textAlign = TextAlign.Center,

                        )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the picture of the output currently

[image]

Thanks in advance
R

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `IntrinsicSize.Max` to `Row` instead of `Column` and add `fillMaxHeight()` modifier inside `Column`

```
@Preview
@Composable
fun SolarToggles(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier
) {
    val options = listOf(
        "Testt off",
        "Testt \n+ Test",
        "Off"
    )
    var selectedOption by remember {
        mutableStateOf("Solar off")
    }
    val onSelectionChange = { text: String ->
        selectedOption = text
    }

    Row(
        modifier = modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .padding(horizontal = 18.dp)
            .clip(shape = RoundedCornerShape(
                size = 3.dp,
            ))
            .height(IntrinsicSize.Max)
            .background(Color.Gray)
    ) {
        options.forEach { text ->
            Column(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(
                        all = 3.dp,
                    )
                    .align(Alignment.CenterVertically)
                    .fillMaxHeight()
                    .background(Color.Red)
                    .weight(1f)
            ) {
                Text(
                    text = text,
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                    textAlign = TextAlign.Center,

                    )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: that's perfect thank you so much, also how would you centre text vertically in your implementation please

Comment: Just need to add add `verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center` in `Column`